# CSS font-face parameters and location

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

My site optimization plugin is telling me to use the `@font-face` .css to make sure my text is visible as early as possible. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that.

Apparently I need to use the following css:

```
    @font-face{
    font-family: 'myWebFont';
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

I have tried parameters such as:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'myWebFont';
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('https://www.treemonkeymusic.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 ') format('woff2');
}
```

Q1: I have no idea which font-family to use, is there a way to figure this out?

Q2: The link is the one shown in the warning I get. But is that the correct link to use? Can I use something like `/wp-content/themes/shop-isle/fonts/blablafont.woff`?

Q3: If I just paste this into the custom css section in Wordpress, will it work? I assume there is potentially an `@font-face` in the css, but it doesn't have the font-display parameter.

Q4: Is there a better way to do this for all fonts to avoid having to do css for each font in use?

Any thoughts or ideas would be welcome as I really don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: check this out [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), it can help generate a font-face kit with assets

Answer (score 0):

**You can use google fonts API**

https://fonts.google.com/

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started